# How to remove an item from a DynamoDB table ? (in swift)

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-dynamodb

Here is some working code, extracting one item from a DynamoDB table:

```
    let dynamoDbObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default(),
    scanExpression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
    scanExpression.limit = 1
    dynamoDbObjectMapper.scan(MyTable.self, expression: scanExpression) {
        [weak self] (output: AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput?, error: Error?) in
        if error != nil {
            print("The request failed. Error: \(String(describing: error))")
        }

        if output != nil {
            currentItem = output!.items[0]
            .. Do useful things with the output ..
            .........
            // Now I want to erase currentItem from the DynamoDB table!
        }
    }
```

I would like to erase currentItem from the table, once this code is run.
*What is the best way to do it?*

I guess that must not be too difficult, but I can't find the solution (meaning a swift example) by searching the net.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45629206/add-remove-one-element-from-a-string-set-in-dynamodbitem

Comment: Thanks, but this is not Swift code and I think it does not do what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case someone else hits the same question.

Here is how I  solved it:

```
    let dynamoDbObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
    dynamoDbObjectMapper.remove(objectToDelete).continueWith(block: {
        (task:AWSTask<AnyObject>!) -> Any? in
        if let error = task.error {
            print("Error in \(#function):\n\(error)")
        }

        return nil
    })
```